# c++11 std::async not working with variadic template parameters by reference

Tags: c++, c++11

How it is possible that this code is not working ?
I would like MyThread::run to work with any kind of parameters, and the parameters being passed by reference and not by value.

http://ideone.com/DUJu5M

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <string>

class MyThread {

        std::future<void> future;

    public:

        template<class... Args>
        MyThread(Args&&... myArgs) :
        future(std::async(std::launch::async, &MyThread::run<Args&&...>, this, std::forward<Args>(myArgs)...))
        {}

        template<class... Args>
        void run(Args&&... myArgs) {}
};

int main() {
    std::string x;
    MyThread thread(x); // Not working
    MyThread thread(10); // Working
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to pass a `reference_wrapper`. It will be unpacked automatically by standard library features like `std::bind`/`std::thread` or `std::async`.

```
int main() {
    std::string x;
    MyThread thread(std::ref(x)); // Not working
    MyThread thread2(10); // Working
    return 0;
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sRKM2YpbbfSgjabk)

Comment: Oh thank you very much. I was not thinking that it is because std::async use a container to store the parameters and that a container cannot contain references.
What do you think if instead I change "std::forward<Args>(myArgs)" to "std::ref(std::forward<Args>(myArgs))" in MyThread to make it generic ?
Thanks

Comment: @user3782790 I'd only pass by reference when there's actual need for it. When you're dealing with multithreaded code it's very easy to get bitten by dangling references.